# Creating custom segment by subtracting one segment from another

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to create a custom segment which is based on 2 other segments?  I have a custom segment ("Segment A") with visitors that performed a certain action.  I would like to see stats for all visitors that DIDN'T perform this action.  So ideally, my custom segment would be:

All Visitors - Segment A = New Segment

Is this possible?

Comment: You're overthinking it. If you create a segment B where (condition) "does not contain" (action) or "does not match regex" for (action) you have what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, you cannot combine segments (no deeper reason, it's just not a function that is not implemented possibly due to the large processing overhead nested segments would incur).

For your particular case still no, but for another reason: "All Visitors" comprises the whole of the data. If you create a segment you remove a part of the data. So "Substracting a group from All Visitors" actually describes the process of creating a new segment in general.

As per my comment you could remove the part of sessions or visitors that do not have a special action by creating a segment where (condition) "does not contain" (action) or "does not match regex" for (action). This would effectively remove those visitors from the "All Visitors" segment.